# Drop Constant columns Non numeric data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i want to drop constant column in a csv file i did this source ,but appearently this code through an exception when data type is Timestamp for example when it is not numeric i think this what i did , is there any help so the source is generalized to work on all types inputs Thanks

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
     val df=spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv(strPath)
        df.printSchema()

     val aggregations = df.columns.map(c => stddev(s"`${c}`").as(c))
    val df2 = df.agg(aggregations.head, aggregations.tail: _*)
    df2.printSchema()
    val columnsToKeep: Seq[String] = (df2.first match {
      case r : Row => r.toSeq.toArray.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double])
    }).zip(df.columns)
      .filter(_._1 != 0) // your special condition is in the filter
      .map(_._2) // keep just the name of the column
     val column=columnsToKeep.map(f=>s"`${f}`")
    val finalResult = df.select(column.head, column.tail : _*)
    finalResult.printSchema()
```

here is an example of data , for example the timestamp column causes problem

```
time.1,col.1,col.2,col.3
2015-12-06 12:40:00,2,2,3
2015-12-07 12:41:35,3,3,3
2015-12-08 12:43:22,4,5,3
2015-12-09 12:47:55,5,7,3
```

Expected result is

```
time.1,col.1,col.2
2015-12-06 12:40:00,2,2
2015-12-07 12:41:35,3,3
2015-12-08 12:43:22,4,5
2015-12-09 12:47:55,5,7
```

since col.3 didn't change.

Comment: can you clean up your codeblock and share example data?

Comment: @mtoto i just did the update check now thanks

Comment: And what's the expected result for this example? It's unclear what you mean by "i want to drop constant column in a csv file" - it looks like you're trying to remove columns for which the first record contains `0` - is that the case? And if so - should the Timestamp column be removed or not?

Comment: @TzachZohar the idea is to remove columns that didn't change in the entire dataset as col.3 for the example , it will remove columns that has standard deviation which is null .It should start by computing the stddev which can be performed only on numeric columns

Comment: Oh, right, sorry - missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Drop constant column*: How about use `countDistinct`:

```
val to_keep = df.columns.collect{ case col if df.agg(countDistinct(s"`${col}`")).first().getAs[Long](0) > 1 => s"`${col}`" }
// to_keep: Array[String] = Array(`time.1`, `col.1`, `col.2`)


df.select(to_keep.head, to_keep.tail: _*).show
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|              time.1|col.1|col.2|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|2015-12-06 12:40:...|    2|    2|
|2015-12-07 12:41:...|    3|    3|
|2015-12-08 12:43:...|    4|    5|
|2015-12-09 12:47:...|    5|    7|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

Or construct the aggregations firstly:

```
val aggs = df.columns.map(col => countDistinct(s"`${col}`").as(col))
// aggs: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(count(DISTINCT `time.1`) AS `time.1`, count(DISTINCT `col.1`) AS `col.1`, count(DISTINCT `col.2`) AS `col.2`, count(DISTINCT `col.3`) AS `col.3`)

val count_map = df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail: _*).first().getValuesMap[Long](df.columns)
// count_map: Map[String,Long] = Map(time.1 -> 4, col.1 -> 4, col.2 -> 4, col.3 -> 1)

val to_keep = df.columns.collect{case col if count_map(col) > 1 => s"`${col}`"}
// to_keep: Array[String] = Array(`time.1`, `col.1`, `col.2`)    

df.select(to_keep.head, to_keep.tail: _*).show
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|              time.1|col.1|col.2|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|2015-12-06 12:40:...|    2|    2|
|2015-12-07 12:41:...|    3|    3|
|2015-12-08 12:43:...|    4|    5|
|2015-12-09 12:47:...|    5|    7|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: thanks very much last question before , for some csv files i got data not in the intial order ,i mean the order column after dropping constant ones changed ,how can i fix it , thanks

Comment: Try the updated method. The columns order messed up because `Map` is unordered, you can collect from the original column names to fix that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cooperation , just want to know , if i had a huge dataset , what is going to be faster should i use the countDiscount or the second method ?Thanks

Comment: The second method should be fast, since it's doing aggregation in one step which might have utilized the optimization under hood. But not sure if the first method is slower. I would go with the second one, but worthwhile to try the first method as well.

Comment: Thanks , last question ,please check the datset i added , i want to count the number of missing values for each columns , the columns who got rows with no value.

Comment: This is completely a different question. You'd better ask a separate Q instead of editing your original question, But `sum(when($"Poids".isNull, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))` for instance could be something you can start with.